# React TableCell is not getting filled inside of nested loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following code. I am also console logging and the console is outputting values for every single piece of content. For some reason my Table.Cell's do not get filled up at all. I believe it is because I have a double nested loop.

```
const CustomToggle = ({ element}) => (

    <Table>
        <Table.Header>
        <Table.Row>
            <Table.HeaderCell>Movies</Table.HeaderCell>
        </Table.Row>
        {Object.keys(element).map(function(dataType) {
            {if (dataType !== "lid" && dataType !== "datacenter")
                {Object.keys(element[dataType]).map(function(data){
                    console.log(element[dataType][data][0])
                    return (<Table.Row>

                        <Table.Cell>{element[dataType][data][0]}</Table.Cell>
                        </Table.Row>
                        )
                    })
                }
            }

    })}
        </Table.Header>
</Table>

);
```

Any idea how I can do this with a double nested loop? The table cells seems to get filled when I just do one loop. I am also getting the following warnings in react:

```
Nested block is redundant
Expected to return a value in function
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need two `{` here. That might be considered as no return or the return value goes nowhere. Also, indentation helps in these situations. Just replace it with the following:

```js
const CustomToggle = ({ element }) => (
  <Table>
    <Table.Header>
      <Table.Row>
        <Table.HeaderCell>Movies</Table.HeaderCell>
      </Table.Row>
      {Object.keys(element).map(function (dataType) {
        if (dataType !== "lid" && dataType !== "datacenter") {
          Object.keys(element[dataType]).map(function (data) {
            console.log(element[dataType][data][0]);
            return (
              <Table.Row>
                <Table.Cell>{element[dataType][data][0]}</Table.Cell>
              </Table.Row>
            );
          });
        }
        return null;
      })}
    </Table.Header>
  </Table>
);
```

Comment: I just tried that and it is still not filling up the table.cells. One warning disappeared, but I am still getting "Expected to return a value in function"

Comment: @Jay266 I have just added a return statement, which is required at the end. Check it out. 

Comment: I just tried it out. There is no more warnings anymore, which is good, but the Table.Cells are still empty. Even though I am console logging it and they have data in every cell. Is there some way to do this without a return of the table row maybe?

Comment: To add to this, I have tried taking out my 2nd for loop, and the cells get filled up. So, is there something about having a 2nd loop that messes things up?

Comment: @Jay266 That's interesting. Can you make a CodeSandbox with the real data mocked into this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
<Table>
        <Table.Header>
        <Table.Row>
            <Table.HeaderCell>Movies</Table.HeaderCell>
        </Table.Row>
        {Object.keys(element).map(function(dataType) {
            {if (dataType !== "lid" && dataType !== "datacenter")
                return Object.keys(element[dataType]).map(function(data){
                    console.log(element[dataType][data][0])
                    return (<Table.Row>

                        <Table.Cell>{element[dataType][data][0]}</Table.Cell>
                        </Table.Row>
                        )
                    })

            }else
              return <></>

    })}
        </Table.Header>
</Table>
```

Comment: What did you change? Looks like it still have the same problem.

Comment: added return statement

Comment: My table.Cells are still empty even though it is console logging with this.

Comment: @SarthakAggarwal Yea, great. It would have been better if you have indented the code. 

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman, yeah my bad, indentation sometimes here is real pain :)